# Does Intellij automatically update classes you've made changes to while in Debug mode?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I know that for css, html, and gsp files you can just refresh the browser without having to rebuild the application in order to see your updated changes. If you're stepping through code in debug mode, and make a change for a groovy or class file, do you have to rebuild the application in order to see the change?

Comment: this highly depends, how your app.  but usually a manually triggered rebuild should do it.  yet this basic hotswapping is very limited (usually only method bodies can be easily swapped) you will end up restarting from time to time nontheless.  spring-loaded (grail's default) or other tools might help here.  beside that, it would help to know, how you run your app and what it is all about.  "groovy application" can mean alot.

Comment: It's a pretty complicated business application; and even in general, for a simple web app, I'm curious to know whether you need to restart the whole application from scratch, or if there's a way intellij can detect your changes in the middle of debugging (stepping through code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ does not update the classes in your running application automatically. You need to compile them manually (this will not be a full project rebuild - IntelliJ will build the project incrementally and compile only the changed classes and the code that depends on them), and then IntelliJ will offer you to reload the changes (which may fail if the changes you made aren't supported by the Java hotswap).

Note that some Web frameworks may be able to reload the changed classes automatically, independently of whether you're running your code from IntelliJ or not.

Comment: If you're running in debug mode, what do you have to do so that you don't have to rebuild from scratch? I've been stepping through code, making changes, but then I have to stop the debugger, and restart it again, which triggers a full build

Comment: You don't have to do anything special; every time you invoke Build | Make Project, IntelliJ performs an incremental build. Also you don't need to stop the debugger; just perform Make while debugging, and IntelliJ will prompt you to reload changed classes.

Comment: run -> reload changed classes

Answer (score 0):

Say you're stopped on a break point, and want to edit the source code of the method you're in. Make the edit, save it, then `run > Reload Changed Classes`. Then, in the debugger controls, `Drop Frame`. Without dropping the frame, you won't execute the your newly recompiled method body.

By default, there's no keybindings for these 2 commands, but you can create them via the `KeyMap` in the settings (ctrl + alt + s). Even better, you can make a [macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) that will execute both these commands for you.

I wish it was easier and automatic, like in eclipse, but oh well.